# How to Append a child to the outerHTML of the father element rather than inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello how to Append a child element using the outerHTML method on the father's element so the icons will go to the outer side of the targeted element rather than inside of it?
in the snippet you will se the icons inside the box I want them out side
in other worlds, I want the icons to be below the box rather than inside
I tried flex and other CSS stuff no luck.

```js
//on select
const deleteExisting = document.querySelectorAll('.solidOnClickDelete');
// Item Lists
const itemRows = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-item-list');
const mondayList = document.getElementById('mondaylist');
// Items
let updateOnLoad = false
// Initialize Arrays
let mondayListArray = [];
let listarrays = [];
// Drag Functionality
let dragged;
let updateRow = false;
let dragging = false;
let currentRow;
// Get Arrays from localStorage if available, set default values if not
function getSavedRows() {

    mondayListArray = ['Work 7.00-15.00', 'Doctor visit'];

}
// Set localStorage Arrays
function updateSavedRows() {
    listarrays = [mondayListArray];
    const arrayNames = ['monday']
    arrayNames.forEach((arrayName, index) => {
        //localStorage.setItem(`${arrayName}Items`, JSON.stringify(listarrays[index]))
    });
}
//Filter to remove null from deleted items //
function filterArray(array) {
    const filteredArray = array.filter(item => item !== null);
    return filteredArray;
}
// Create DOM Elements for each list item
function createItemEl(rowEl, row, item, index) {
  // List Item
  const listEl = document.createElement('li')
  listEl.classList.add('day-item');
  listEl.textContent = item;
  listEl.draggable = true;
  listEl.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)')
  listEl.contentEditable = true;
  listEl.id = index;
  const divOptions = document.createElement('span');
  divOptions.classList.add('father', 'hidden');
  divOptions.contentEditable = false;
  listEl.onfocus = () => divOptions.classList.remove('hidden');
  listEl.onblur = () => divOptions.classList.add('hidden');
  const iconDelete = document.createElement('i');
  const iconYes = document.createElement('i');
  iconYes.classList.add('far', 'fa-check-circle', 'fa-2x');
  iconDelete.classList.add('far', 'fa-times-circle', 'fa-2x');
  iconYes.setAttribute('onclick', `updateItem(${index}, ${row})`);
  iconDelete.setAttribute('onclick', `deleteItemOnClick(${index}, ${row})`);
  //Append everything // 
  rowEl.appendChild(listEl);
  listEl.appendChild(divOptions);
  divOptions.appendChild(iconYes);
  divOptions.appendChild(iconDelete);
};
// Update Columns in DOM - Reset HTML, Filter Array, Update localStorage
function updateDOM() {
    // Check localStorage once
    if (!updateOnLoad) {
        getSavedRows();
    }
    mondayList.textContent = '';
    mondayListArray.forEach((mondayitem, index) => {
        createItemEl(mondayList, 0, mondayitem, index);
    });
    mondayListArray = filterArray(mondayListArray)
    updateOnLoad = true;
    updateSavedRows();
}
// Delete on click - // 
function deleteItemOnClick(id, row) {
    //let deleteItem = document.getElementsByClassName('solidOnClickDelete');
    const selectedArray = listarrays[row];
    delete selectedArray[id]

    /*
      deleteItem[0].onclick = function () { delete selectedArray[id] };
      console.log(deleteItem[0]);
      updateDOM();*/
    updateDOM();
};
// add To Task Array 
function addToRow(row) {
    const itemText = addTask[row].textContent;
    const selectedArray = listarrays[row];
    selectedArray.push(itemText);
    addTask[row].textContent = '';
    updateDOM();
}
// reBuild Arrays
function rebulidArrays() {
    mondayListArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < mondayList.children.length; i++) {
        mondayListArray.push(mondayList.children[i].textContent);
    }
    updateDOM();
}
// On Load
updateDOM();
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  :root {
  /* Light Theme Default */ 
  /* Main Colors */ 
    --primary-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --primary-variant: #b9b9b9;
    --secondary-color: #5c5c5c;
  /* Text on Main Colors */  
    --on-primary: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    --on-background: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    --on-background-alt: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.952);
  /* Background */
    --background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Box Shadow */ 
    --box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 1px rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.5);
  }
  [data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
    --primary-variant: #777777;
    --secondary-color: #e4e4e4;
    --on-primary: rgb(173, 173, 173);
    --on-background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    --on-background-alt: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    --background: #202020;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    color: var(--on-primary); 
     background-color:var(--primary-color);
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 
  }
 
  .slider.round::before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
 
  .main-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: var(--on-background);
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .main-container {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  .days-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  /* rows / poulation */
  .day-row,.populating-btns {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.4);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
  }
  .dayFunction {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  .Flex-right {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
  
  }
  .Monday-row .header,
  
  .Monday-row .over {
    background-color: var( --on-primary);
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .day-item {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color:var(--secondary-color);
    color: var(--primary-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    
  }
  .day-item:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Add Button Group */
  .add-btns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
  }
  .add-btn {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .add-task {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:var(--on-primary);
    color:var(--on-background-alt);
  }
  .add-btn,.add-task:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: black;
  }
  .add-btn:active {
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  .add-btn-extend {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgba(12, 178, 207, 0.603);
  }
  .add-btn-extend:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: black;
  }
  .solidOnClick , .solidOnClickDelete {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: var(--primary-variant);
  }
  .solidonclick:hover{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    filter: brightness(95%);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.842);
  }
  
  .father {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.fa-check-circle {
  color: green;
}
.fa-times-circle {
  color: red;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <li class="day-row Monday-row">
        <div id="Mondaycontent">
            <ul id="mondaylist" class="drag-item-list Flex-right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="dropin(event)"
                ondragenter="dragenter(0)">
            </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
        <!--Add Task To Li Later showInputBox()-->
        <div class="add-container">
            <div class="add-item" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>
    </li>

</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: just to make sure I understand.. if I have `<div><span id="elem"></span></div>` I want to append an element to `elem`'s parent which would be `div` like `<div><span id="elem"></span><b class="father"></b></div>`?

Comment: <Div> then father then child (Child must be in the outer side // After ) </Div>

Comment: ok can you edit your question to have an example result because im confused :{

Comment: you can check the snippet now :D

Comment: the icons are inside the box I cannot find a way to put them out side I used Flex, appended to other place absolutely no luck.

Comment: Your HTML is highly invalid and **must be fixed first**. `li` **must** be a child of `ol` or `ul`. Also, the only child elements `html` can have is `head` and `body` (you also have `script`). Lastly, note that there is no such thing as a *father element* - elements are gender neutral and as such, you talk about **parent** elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of HTML semantics, a list item `<li>` tag should only be used inside of an unordered `<ul>` or ordered `<ol>` list. There is a list element acting as the parent container `<li class="day-row Monday-row">` so that should probably be changed to a `<div>`.

The `<script>` tag for your external JavaScript file is also placed outside the `<body>` which is invalid. It needs to be placed before the body close `</body>` or within the `<head>` for the page to load the script.

To address moving the checkmark and red X icons outside of the list item content box after clicking the items, you can simply append those `<span>` tags into the outer container `<div id="MondayContent">`.

```js
function createItemEl(rowEl, row, item, index) {
   // parent container
   const parentDiv = document.querySelector("#Mondaycontent");
   ...
   // append icons to parent container
   parentDiv.appendChild(divOptions);
}
```

Lastly, use CSS and some JavaScript to position the icons accordingly under each list item.

After the `updateDOM()` method, I positioned the second `<span>` tag underneath the "Doctor visit" list item. Instead of using JavaScript, you could also target that tag using a CSS selector such as `.father:last-child`.

```js
// Position the icons for Doctor visit item
const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".father");
icons[1].style.left = "12.5rem";
```

```css
 /* Parent div container */
  #Mondaycontent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #Mondaycontent .father {
    position: relative;
    left: 3rem;
    width: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
  }
  /* Use this if you don't want to style the second span tag with JS */
  #Mondaycontent .father:last-child {
    left: 12.5rem;
  }
```

```js
//on select
const deleteExisting = document.querySelectorAll('.solidOnClickDelete');
// Item Lists
const itemRows = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-item-list');
const mondayList = document.getElementById('mondaylist');
// Items
let updateOnLoad = false
// Initialize Arrays
let mondayListArray = [];
let listarrays = [];
// Drag Functionality
let dragged;
let updateRow = false;
let dragging = false;
let currentRow;
// Get Arrays from localStorage if available, set default values if not
function getSavedRows() {

    mondayListArray = ['Work 7.00-15.00', 'Doctor visit'];

}
// Set localStorage Arrays
function updateSavedRows() {
    listarrays = [mondayListArray];
    const arrayNames = ['monday']
    arrayNames.forEach((arrayName, index) => {
        //localStorage.setItem(`${arrayName}Items`, JSON.stringify(listarrays[index]))
    });
}
//Filter to remove null from deleted items //
function filterArray(array) {
    const filteredArray = array.filter(item => item !== null);
    return filteredArray;
}
// Create DOM Elements for each list item
function createItemEl(rowEl, row, item, index) {
  // parent container
  const parentDiv = document.querySelector("#Mondaycontent");
  // List Item
  const listEl = document.createElement('li')
  listEl.classList.add('day-item');
  listEl.textContent = item;
  listEl.draggable = true;
  listEl.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)')
  listEl.contentEditable = true;
  listEl.id = index;
  const divOptions = document.createElement('span');
  divOptions.classList.add('father', 'hidden');
  divOptions.contentEditable = false;
  listEl.onfocus = () => divOptions.classList.remove('hidden');
  listEl.onblur = () => divOptions.classList.add('hidden');
  const iconDelete = document.createElement('i');
  const iconYes = document.createElement('i');
  iconYes.classList.add('far', 'fa-check-circle', 'fa-2x');
  iconDelete.classList.add('far', 'fa-times-circle', 'fa-2x');
  iconYes.setAttribute('onclick', `updateItem(${index}, ${row})`);
  iconDelete.setAttribute('onclick', `deleteItemOnClick(${index}, ${row})`);
  //Append everything // 
  rowEl.appendChild(listEl);
  listEl.appendChild(divOptions);
  parentDiv.appendChild(divOptions);
  divOptions.appendChild(iconYes);
  divOptions.appendChild(iconDelete);
};

// Update Columns in DOM - Reset HTML, Filter Array, Update localStorage
function updateDOM() {
    // Check localStorage once
    if (!updateOnLoad) {
        getSavedRows();
    }
    mondayList.textContent = '';
    mondayListArray.forEach((mondayitem, index) => {
        createItemEl(mondayList, 0, mondayitem, index);
    });
    mondayListArray = filterArray(mondayListArray)
    updateOnLoad = true;
    updateSavedRows();
}
// Delete on click - // 
function deleteItemOnClick(id, row) {
    //let deleteItem = document.getElementsByClassName('solidOnClickDelete');
    const selectedArray = listarrays[row];
    delete selectedArray[id]

    /*
      deleteItem[0].onclick = function () { delete selectedArray[id] };
      console.log(deleteItem[0]);
      updateDOM();*/
    updateDOM();
};
// add To Task Array 
function addToRow(row) {
    const itemText = addTask[row].textContent;
    const selectedArray = listarrays[row];
    selectedArray.push(itemText);
    addTask[row].textContent = '';
    updateDOM();
}
// reBuild Arrays
function rebulidArrays() {
    mondayListArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < mondayList.children.length; i++) {
        mondayListArray.push(mondayList.children[i].textContent);
    }
    updateDOM();
}

// On Load
updateDOM();

// Position the span tags for doctor visit item
const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".father");
icons[1].style.left = "12.5rem";
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  :root {
  /* Light Theme Default */ 
  /* Main Colors */ 
    --primary-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --primary-variant: #b9b9b9;
    --secondary-color: #5c5c5c;
  /* Text on Main Colors */  
    --on-primary: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    --on-background: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    --on-background-alt: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.952);
  /* Background */
    --background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Box Shadow */ 
    --box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 1px rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.5);
  }
  [data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
    --primary-variant: #777777;
    --secondary-color: #e4e4e4;
    --on-primary: rgb(173, 173, 173);
    --on-background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    --on-background-alt: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    --background: #202020;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    color: var(--on-primary); 
     background-color:var(--primary-color);
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 
  }
 
  .slider.round::before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
 
  .main-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: var(--on-background);
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .main-container {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  .days-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  /* Parent div container */
  #Mondaycontent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #Mondaycontent .father {
    position: relative;
    left: 3rem;
    width: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
  }
  #Mondaycontent .father:last-child {
    left: 12.5rem;
  }
  /* rows / poulation */
  .day-row,.populating-btns {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.4);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
  }
  .dayFunction {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  .Flex-right {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
  
  }
  .Monday-row .header,
  
  .Monday-row .over {
    background-color: var( --on-primary);
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .day-item {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color:var(--secondary-color);
    color: var(--primary-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    
  }
  .day-item:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Add Button Group */
  .add-btns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
  }
  .add-btn {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .add-task {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:var(--on-primary);
    color:var(--on-background-alt);
  }
  .add-btn,.add-task:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: black;
  }
  .add-btn:active {
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  .add-btn-extend {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgba(12, 178, 207, 0.603);
  }
  .add-btn-extend:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: black;
  }
  .solidOnClick , .solidOnClickDelete {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: var(--primary-variant);
  }
  .solidonclick:hover{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    filter: brightness(95%);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.842);
  }
  
  .father {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.fa-check-circle {
  color: green;
}
.fa-times-circle {
  color: red;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="day-row Monday-row">
        <div id="Mondaycontent">
            <ul id="mondaylist" class="drag-item-list Flex-right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="dropin(event)"
                ondragenter="dragenter(0)">
            </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
        <!--Add Task To Li Later showInputBox()-->
        <div class="add-container">
            <div class="add-item" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Include external JS Script at body close or within <head> -->
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```